# Supply Spring managed objects to non Spring managed Objects?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a data structure representing a CSV file containing thousands of config settings.  The structure is a Java class file with instance variables to represent the records in the file (ie: a `HashMap`) and the state of the file (errors, warnings, etc).

These classes are not created by Spring as they have state.  I would like the class to access system configuration properties which are currently handled by a Spring managed database DAO class.  Usually when classes need this DAO I inject it through Spring using `@Autowired`.  But as my data structure is not managed by Spring, how can the CSV structure class access the DAO?

The only method I can think of is when creating the data structure from the Spring managed bean to just pass in the DAO:

```
CSVDataStruture c = new CSVDataStruture(dao);
```

Comment: You can directly refer to the managed bean through the spring context' getBean method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These classes are not created by Spring as they have state.

What makes you think that Spring cannot / should not create objects that have state?

Depending on what you are trying to do (it is hard to figure this out!) I would do one of the following:

- Give the CSV class getters and setters for a CVS file parameter and a DAO parameter, and instantiate it using Spring DI.  This assumes that the filename is available when Spring wiring occurs.
- Create a factory class with a method that instantiates a CSV object from a file parameter.  The factory class should have a getter/setter for the DAO object and be instantiated using Spring DI.

Comment: Thanks - think I'll try option 2.  What we're doing is loading a file, validating the contents, then loading a second file and diff'ing the two files.

Answer (score 3):

See [6.8.1. Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html) about using `@Configurable`

Another way is to get ahold of the application context (in web applications this is `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext)`) and get the beans using `context.getBean("name")`, but it is more of a workaround.

Comment: `@Configurable` is the way to go